# Attempting to deploy MySQL and Node.js app to heroku, no deployment when running heroku local, success but no browser

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, deployment

Hi this is my first time building a node.js app with MySQL as the database, I am attempting to deploy the app to heroku. I have figured out the connection to MySQL using the add-on cleardb. Now all that is left is for me to deploy it. So before actually deploying the app I am attempting to test it locally. So I run the command `heroku local` and all that I am seeing is `server running on 8080!` I have configured the Procfile to point to my file app.js. Everything runs successfully but the app simply won't launch. I also tried configuring a start script but the same thing occurs. this is the repository to my app: https://github.com/ruben-olmos/join-us-app.

the repository is small and brief. Is this a problem with the code? I ran this locally on cloud 9 and it worked but it doesn't seem to work here. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share heroku logs using heroku logs --tail. It will help figuring out the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` there is no start script so Heroku needs a start script to run your app ie `npm start`

Solution:

in your `package.json`, add :

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./app.js"
  },
```

So, now your Heroku knows which app to run.

And the second issue being, your MySQL connection is on localhost so, did you change it on heroku?

f you really want to use mysql, you have two paths to follow.

1. Run mysql locally, but convert to postgres when migrating to Heroku using the mysql2psql gem, as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql
2. Use a mysql addon like https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb

Comment: Hi I updated the code to include the start script, I had already included the connection with cleardb, everything was perfectly assigned. However I am still getting the same issue with only a server running on 5000 error and nothing else

Comment: Lame question but, did you add the env variables to heroku? Also where exactly you are getting error. Check logs?